# Sobolev embedding counterexample

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, sobolev-spaces, holder-spaces

I am trying to find a counterexample to show that $$W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R ^n}) \nsubseteq C^{0,\alpha}(\mathbb{R^n}) $$

for $p>n$ and $\alpha \le 1 -\frac{n}{p}$.

No clue yet, thanks for your help.

Comment: Try the function $|x|^b$ with $b>0$. To what Sobolev spaces does it belong?

Comment: We need that $p(b-1) < -2$ to have $D(|x|^b) \in L_p$ ??

Comment: Okay, first of all let's focus on unit ball, the function could be smoothly cutoff (multiplying it by a bump) so that infinity is not an issue. Second, I think you meant $p(b-1)<-n$, where $n$ is the dimension. That would be correct. Now contrast this with the fact that $|x|^b$ is not in $C^\alpha$ when $\alpha>b$.

Comment: Ahahaha thanks, I know what to do!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Summary of comments). Let $u(x) = |x|^b$ on the unit ball, and $0$ outside. Choose $b>0$ appropriately.

The function $u$ is absolutely continuous on every line. Also,  $|\nabla u|\in L^p$ whenever  $p(b-1) > -n$, so $u\in W^{1,p}$ under this condition. On the other hand, $u\notin C^\alpha$ when $\alpha>b$.

Conclusion: if $\alpha> 1-n/p$, we can choose $b$ to satisfy both $p(b-1) > -n$ and $\alpha>b$, thus obtaining a counterexample.